# Asymptotic equivalence of two binomial summations obtained from splitting up terms in a Vandermonde identity

Tags: combinatorics

for the binomials, say $q_n$ is even and $q_n^2/n\to\infty$ and$q_n/n \to0$,
$${n\choose q_n}=\sum_{k=0}{q_n\choose 2k}{n-q_n\choose {q_n-2k}}+\sum_{k=0}{q_n\choose 2k+1}{n-q_n\choose {q_n-2k-1}}$$
by considering  $(1+x)^n=(1+x)^{q_n}(1+x)^{n-q_n}$ by choosing even and odd. Is is true that $$\sum_{k=0}{q_n\choose 2k}{n-q_n\choose {q_n-2k}}/\sum_{k=0}{q_n\choose 2k+1}{n-q_n\choose {q_n-2k-1}}\to 1?$$How to prove this?

Comment: what's $q_n/n^2\to\infty$?

Comment: sorry, there is a typo,i change it,  but basically what I mean is the coefficient of x^{q_n} has two parts, one is by the  odd summation, the other is by the even summation, what I want to see is that two coefficients contributed by the two summations are asymptotic the same